# Please help in completely converting raw sql to SQLAlchemy code(I tried but not there yet)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I hope all are well. First off, all I'm sorry that my SQL isn't great.

I've a raw SQL that looks like following

```
select a.appointmentId, a.patientId, r.MaxTime from (
    select appointmentid, patientid, max(apptDate) as MaxTime
        from appointment 
        where facilityid=95
        group by patientid
    ) r
inner join

Appointment a on 
a.patientid = r.patientid and 
a.apptDate = r.MaxTime
```

I'm using declarative style of SQLAlchemy in my code and here is how my query looks like

```
appt_query = alchemy_session.query(Appointment.appointmentId, Appointment.patientId,          func.max(Appointment.apptDate).label('maxTime')).filter(

        Appointment.facilityId == 95,

).group_by(Appointment.patientId).subquery()


 appointments  = alchemy_session.query(Appointment.appointmentId, Appointment.patientId,    appt_query.c.maxTime).outerjoin(

            appt_query, and_(
                Appointment.patientId == appt_query.c.patientId,
                Appointment.apptDate == appt_query.c.maxTime
            )

)
```

but when I do

print appointments

It's unfortunately not producing the SQL that I want. I know there are lapses in my understanding of SQL so any pointers on this will be really helpful. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Other than the `inner join` in raw SQL versus the `outerjoin()` in SQLAlchemy, I can't really notice the difference. What is the SQL that get produced?

Comment: If you have access to the MetaData object, metadata.bind.echo = True will show you the SQL that sqlalchemy is using.

Answer (score 0):

as sayap mentions, this is very close to being the same query.  After you've fixed the `.outerjoin()` to `.join()`, the onlything left is to give one instance of `Appointment` an alias so that the subquery won't be correlated.  that's nicely done by `sqlalchemy.orm.aliased`:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased, Query
>>> appt_alias = aliased(Appointment)
>>> appt_query = Query([Appointment.appointmentId,
...                     Appointment.patientId,
...                     func.max(Appointment.apptDate).label('maxTime')]) \
...             .filter(Appointment.facilityId == 95,) \
...             .group_by(Appointment.patientId) \
...             .subquery()
>>> appointments  = Query([appt_alias.appointmentId,
...                        appt_alias.patientId,
...                        appt_query.c.maxTime]) \
...                 .join(appt_query, and_(
...                     appt_alias.patientId == appt_query.c.patientId,
...                     appt_alias.apptDate == appt_query.c.maxTime) )
>>> 
>>> print appointments
SELECT appointment_1."appointmentId" AS "appointment_1_appointmentId", appointment_1."patientId" AS "appointment_1_patientId", anon_1."maxTime" AS "anon_1_maxTime" 
FROM appointment AS appointment_1 JOIN (SELECT appointment."appointmentId" AS "appointmentId", appointment."patientId" AS "patientId", max(appointment."apptDate") AS "maxTime" 
FROM appointment 
WHERE appointment."facilityId" = :facilityId_1 GROUP BY appointment."patientId") AS anon_1 ON appointment_1."patientId" = anon_1."patientId" AND appointment_1."apptDate" = anon_1."maxTime"
```